# How to remove a specific column while exporting to PDF c#?

Tags: c#, itext

I've four columns in a `datagridview`. When I select some rows from that `datagridview` and hit a button or something I want to create a pdf table consisting of those selected rows but ignore the column 2 data in the pdf table. How can I do that?

Sample code I've done (which shows all 4 columns data):

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
{
  PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(column.HeaderText,headerFont));
  cell.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(215, 20, 130);
  cell.Border=0;
  pdfTable.AddCell(cell);
}

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
  foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
  {
     pdfTable.AddCell(new Phrase(cell.Value.ToString(),standardFont));
  }
}
```

But, I don't want the 2nd column data to be exported to the pdf.

Can you help me to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Which 2 columns are you trying to ignore?

Comment: Not 2 columns...I'm trying to ignore only column no. 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int i = 0;

foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
{ 
  i++;
  if(i == 2) continue;
  PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(column.HeaderText,headerFont));
  cell.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(215, 20, 130);
  cell.Border=0;
  pdfTable.AddCell(cell);
}

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
  i = 0;
  foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
  {
     i++;
     if(i == 2) continue;
     pdfTable.AddCell(new Phrase(cell.Value.ToString(),standardFont));
  }
}
```

This generated
[image]

Comment: I've added your codes output screenshot in your solution

Comment: I have made some edits on the code, can you try again?

Comment: can `Skip` method be used somehow in this situation?